# How to track a specific file changes using MVVM pattern in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a .NET WPF project using Visual Studio 2022 and I added tray icon functionality to my app. I am managing tray icon part in mainwindow.xaml.cs but i need to track file changes in my mainviewmodel class as well. How can i pass this event to mvvm or maybe pass data to mainviewmodel ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
        {
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = nameof(AppStateModel);
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var appState = CheckAppState();
        AppState = appState;
        string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;


        string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.FullName;
        var path = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "Assets");

        switch (appState)
        {
            case 1:
                m_notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.Combine(path, "48x48_active.ico"));
                break;
            case 2:
                m_notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.Combine(path, "48x48_inactive.ico"));
                break;
            case 4:
                m_notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.Combine(path, "48x48_running.ico"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private int CheckAppState()
    {
        try
        {
            var tempFile = Path.Combine(AppWizard.Default.FolderPath, nameof(AppStateModel));

            if (!File.Exists(tempFile))
                return -1;

            var _path = tempFile;
            using (var stream = new FileStream
                (_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var appStateModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppStateModel>(File.ReadAllText(tempFile));
                if (appStateModel != null)
                {
                    if (appStateModel.CurrentState == AppStates.Ready)
                        return 1;

                    else if (appStateModel.CurrentState == AppStates.Dead || appStateModel.CurrentState == AppStates.Expired)
                        return 2;

                    else if (appStateModel.CurrentState == AppStates.Busy)
                        return 4;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileLogger.Default.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add this function directly into the MainViewModel?

Comment: There are a lot of ways for doing this, but it depends on how you project is designed. You can have a separate service that does this then use Mediator  pattern, or other messaging methods or just delegate methods to pass that info to the view model

Comment: There is a reason: my TrayIcon functionality works in mainwindow.xaml.cs and I change Icon according to the file changes. So, if i move this functions to MainViewModel, I will have trouble to call them in mainwindows.xaml.cs I guess.

Comment: Actually, I need to do it as simple as possible. Without changing the general structure of my code and patterns I use.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to pass it to mainview model using delegate methods?

Comment: How do you add the DataContext to your view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251489/discussion-between-radu-hatos-and-kaan-caghan).

Comment: You should pretty much never use thread.sleep now. That code looks like it's going to fire on your ui thread and you'll block that with thread.sleep.  Use await task.delay() instead,

Comment: Radu and Andy, thank you very much. Not only solved my problem but also prevented possible problems I will face in future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In an MVVM context you would implement such logic in the Model. The Model can notify the View Model about changes using events. The complete file handling logic (data persistence) belongs to the Model and not View Model. The View Model only fetches data from the Model and prepares it for exposition to the View.

Answer (score 1):

A watcher service may look as following:

```
public class FileWatcherService
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        public FileWatcherService()
        {
            CreateFileWatcher();
        }
        public event EventHandler<FileSystemEventArgs> FileChanged;
        
        public void CreateFileWatcher()
        {
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Temp");

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                                 | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.Security
                                 | NotifyFilters.Size;

            watcher.Changed += MakeANote;
            watcher.Created += MakeANote;
            watcher.Deleted += MakeANote;
            watcher.Renamed += MakeANote;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        private void MakeANote(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            FileChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
```

A simple way is to put the "watcher" in the View Model :

```
public class MainViewModel :Binding
{
    FileWatcherService _fileWatcherService = new FileWatcherService();
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _fileWatcherService.FileChanged += OnFileChanged;
    }

    private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        LastAction = e.ChangeType.ToString();
        File = e.Name;
    }

    string _lastAction;
    public string LastAction
    {
        get { return _lastAction; }
        set { _lastAction = value;NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(LastAction)); }
    }
    string _file;
    public string File
    {
        get { return _file; }
        set { _file = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(File)); }
    }



}
```

And the sample XAML code will be as following:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding File}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" has "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastAction}"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```